# Entity Framework get all data from table with foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

Please help. I can not resolve the issue - the category name is null.
Thanks a lot.
The models
public class Product
{
[Key]
public int ProductID { get; set; }
public string ProductName { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public double Price { get; set; }

```
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }




public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }
```

`
Product Controller

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ProductDto>> GetProductsAsync()
{
    List<Product> products = await _db.Products
                                      .Include(u => u.Category)
                                      .ToListAsync();
    return _mapper.Map<List<ProductDto>>(products);
}



public class MappingProfiles : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfiles()
        {
            CreateMap<ProductDto, Product>().ReverseMap();
        }
    }
 public class ProductDto
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

How to resolve null fields?

[image]

Comment: What .net version you are using?

Comment: The version is CORE 6

Comment: Just check this link - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-handle-nullable-reference-in-net-6/. Net 6 has nullable reference type changes.

Comment: I have to see the name of cayegory

Comment: Hi @LeonidNisanov, what is your `ProductDto`? How do you configure your automapper?

Comment: Issue was updated with your request to  ProductDto and Mapper.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Rena added screen

Comment: Hi @LeonidNisanov, updated with answer below, pls check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `MappingProfiles` like below:

```
public class MappingProfiles : Profile
{
    public MappingProfiles()
    {
        CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>()
            .ForMember(d => d.CategoryName, a => a.MapFrom(s => s.Category.CategoryName))
            .ReverseMap()
            .ForPath(b => b.Category, o => o.MapFrom(dto => (Category)null));
  
    }
}
```